# Efficient way to fill a 3D array

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

I’m trying to find an efficient way to fill a 3D array. In particular, I want to fill the array's columns with the values of the previous columns.

Here is a reproducible example.

```
set.seed(1234)
no_ind <- 10
time_period <- 8

## Define the 3D array
col_array <- c(paste("day_", seq(0, 7, 1), sep=""))
test <- array(0, dim=c(time_period, length(col_array), no_ind), dimnames=list(NULL, col_array, as.character(seq(1, no_ind, 1))))
print(test)

## Initialize the array
test[1,c("day_0"),] <- round(runif(no_ind, 0, 100))
print(test)

## Fill the array
for(time in 1:(time_period - 1)){
for(ind in 1:no_ind){
  ## print(time)
  ## print(ind)
    test[time + 1,c("day_0"),ind] <- round(runif(1, 0, 100))
    test[time + 1,c("day_1"),ind] <- test[time,c("day_0"),ind]
    test[time + 1,c("day_2"),ind] <- test[time,c("day_1"),ind]
    test[time + 1,c("day_3"),ind] <- test[time,c("day_2"),ind]
    test[time + 1,c("day_4"),ind] <- test[time,c("day_3"),ind]
    test[time + 1,c("day_5"),ind] <- test[time,c("day_4"),ind]
    test[time + 1,c("day_6"),ind] <- test[time,c("day_5"),ind]
    test[time + 1,c("day_7"),ind] <- test[time,c("day_6"),ind]
  }
}

print(test)
```

In reality, my 3D array contains 366 rows, 8 columns and 10000 observations for the 3rd dimension. How can I automate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of `sapply`s implicit (by default) `simplify = TRUE` parameter and generate the 3D array in one step using `replicate`

```
dims <- c(8, 8, 10)   # The dimensions of your array
set.seed(2017)
arr <- replicate(dims[3], {
    rand <- round(runif(dims[1], 0, 100));
    sapply(seq_along(1:dims[1]), function(i)
        c(rep(0, i - 1), rand[1:(dims[1] - i + 1)])) })
```

`sapply(...)` has `simplify = TRUE` by default, and returns an array with values in the lower triangular part according to your specifications. `replicate` will then repeat the process 10 times. This also reduces the number of `runif` calls, as we draw `10` times `8` random numbers, rather than `10x8=80` random numbers individually.

Comment: Great ! Thank you very much Maurits for your help. If I keep the first loop over the "time", how can I only simplify the 2nd loop over the 3rd dimension "ind"?

Comment: @Pierre I’m sorry but I don’t understand your question. I thought the goal was to optimise your code? My code produces the same output structure as your example.

Comment: Yes, the goal was to optimize the code but I have wondered if it was possible to optimize the code within the loop `for(ind in 1:no_ind)` by keeping the loop `for(time in 1:(time_period - 1))` fixed. Thus, in this case, the code structure would be: `for(time in 1:(time_period - 1)){ *** optimized code***}}`