# Fastest way to fill a 3D array from another 3D arrray in R

Tags: arrays, r

I am using the code below to fill a 3D array from another 3D array. I have used the `sapply` function to apply the code lines at each individual (3rd dimension) as in [Efficient way to fill a 3D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51297035/efficient-way-to-fill-a-3d-array).
Here is my code.

```
ind <- 1000
    individuals <- as.character(seq(1, ind, by = 1))
    maxCol <- 7
    col <- 4
    line <- 0
    a <- 0
    b <- 0
    c <- 0

    col_array <- c("year","time", "ID", "age", as.vector(outer(c(paste(seq(0, 1, by = 1), "year", sep="_"), paste(seq(2, maxCol, by = 1), "years", sep="_")), c("S_F", "I_F", "R_F"), paste, sep="_")))
    array1 <- array(sample(1:100, length(col_array), replace = T), dim=c(2, length(col_array), ind), dimnames=list(NULL, col_array, individuals)) ## 3rd dimension = individual ID
    ## print(array1)

    col_array <- c("year","time", "ID", "age", as.vector(outer(c(paste(seq(0, 1, by = 1), "year", sep="_"), paste(seq(2, maxCol, by = 1), "years", sep="_")), c("S_M", "I_M", "R_M"), paste, sep="_")))
    array2 <- array(NA, dim=c(2, length(col_array), ind), dimnames=list(NULL, col_array, individuals)) ## 3rd dimension = individual ID
    ## print(array2)

    tic("array2")
    array2 <- sapply(individuals, function(i){

      ## Fill the first columns
      array2[line + 1, c("year", "time", "ID", "age"), i] <- c(a, b, i, c)

      ## Define column indexes for individuals S
      col_start_S_F <- which(colnames(array1[,,i])=="0_year_S_F")
      col_end_S_F <- which(colnames(array1[,,i])==paste(maxCol,"years_S_F", sep="_"))
      col_start_S_M <- which(colnames(array2[,,i])=="0_year_S_M")
      col_end_S_M <- which(colnames(array2[,,i])==paste(maxCol,"years_S_M", sep="_"))

      ## Fill the columns for individuals S
      p_S_M <- sapply(0:maxCol, function(x){pnorm(x, 4, 1)})
      array2[line + 1, col_start_S_M:col_end_S_M, i] <- round(as.numeric(as.vector(array1[line + 1, col_start_S_F:col_end_S_F, i]))*p_S_M)

      ## Define column indexes for individuals I
      col_start_I_F <- which(colnames(array1[,,i])=="0_year_I_F")
      col_end_I_F <- which(colnames(array1[,,i])==paste(maxCol,"years_I_F", sep="_"))
      col_start_I_M <- which(colnames(array2[,,i])=="0_year_I_M")
      col_end_I_M <- which(colnames(array2[,,i])==paste(maxCol,"years_I_M", sep="_"))

      ## Fill the columns for individuals I
      p_I_M <- sapply(0:maxCol, function(x){pnorm(x, 2, 1)})
      array2[line + 1, col_start_I_M:col_end_I_M, i] <- round(as.numeric(as.vector(array1[line + 1, col_start_I_F:col_end_I_F, i]))*p_I_M)

      ## Define column indexes for individuals R
      col_start_R_M <- which(colnames(array2[,,i])=="0_year_R_M")
      col_end_R_M <- which(colnames(array2[,,i])==paste(maxCol,"years_R_M", sep="_"))

      ## Fill the columns for individuals R
      array2[line + 1, col_start_R_M:col_end_R_M, i] <- as.numeric(as.vector(array2[line + 1, col_start_S_M:col_end_S_M, i])) + 
        as.numeric(as.vector(array2[line + 1, col_start_I_M:col_end_I_M, i]))

      return(array2[,,i])
      ## print(array2[,,i])

    }, simplify = "array") 
    ## print(array2)
    toc()
```

Is there a way to increase the performance/speed of my code (i.e., < 1 sec)? There are 500000 observations for the 3rd dimension. Any suggestions?

Comment: This suspiciously looks like you should use a long-format data.table instead if an array.

Comment: I agree with @Roland. It looks like it will be much faster if you can vectorize and process a long table instead of looping through and applying similar calculations separately for 500k individuals.  I'm trying out a solution using the `dplyr` and `tidyr` that might be fast enough; if not, I'm sure someone else could figure a faster solution with data.table or base R.

Comment: Is your sample code performing correctly? The `array2` function seems never to touch the 2nd element in the 1st dimension (just 1st element = "line 0 + 1"), so I wasn't sure what that dimension was for.

Comment: Wouldn't the array be better off with more than 3 dimensions?  `year, `time`, `ID`, and `age` could be separate dimensions.

Comment: @Jon Spring: Yes, it's correct. The function uses only the first row in the array1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR: Here's a tidyverse solution that transforms the sample array into a dataframe and applies the requested changes.** EDIT: I've added steps 1+2 to transform the original post's sample data into the format I used in step 3. The actual calculation in Step 3 is very fast (<0.1 sec), but the bottleneck is step 2, which takes 10 seconds for 500k rows.

Step 0: Create sample data for 500k individuals

```
ind <- 500000
individuals <- as.character(seq(1, ind, by = 1))
maxCol <- 7
col <- 4
line <- 0
a <- 0
b <- 0
c <- 0

col_array <- c("year","time", "ID", "age", as.vector(outer(c(paste(seq(0, 1, by = 1), "year", sep="_"), paste(seq(2, maxCol, by = 1), "years", sep="_")), c("S_F", "I_F", "R_F"), paste, sep="_")))
array1 <- array(sample(1:100, length(col_array), replace = T), dim=c(2, length(col_array), ind), dimnames=list(NULL, col_array, individuals)) ## 3rd dimension = individual ID

dim(array1)
# [1]      2     28 500000    # Two rows x 28 measures x 500k individuals
```

Step 1: Subset array and convert to data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)
# OP only uses first line of array1. If other rows needed, replace with "array1 %>%"
#   and adjust renaming below to account for different Var1.
array1_dt <- array1[1,,] %>% 
  as.data.frame.table(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Step 2: Break out the stats into different columns, with one row for each individual-year. This is the slowest step (especially the `spread` line), and takes 0.05 sec for 1000 individuals but 10 seconds for 500k. I expect a data.table solution could make it much faster, if needed.

```
array1_dt_reshape <- array1_dt %>%
  rename(stat = Var1, ID = Var2) %>%
  filter(!stat %in% c("year", "time", "ID", "age")) %>%
  mutate(year = stat %>% str_sub(end = 1),
         col  = stat %>% str_sub(start = -3)) %>%
  select(-stat) %>%
  spread(col, Freq) %>%
  arrange(ID)
```

Step 3: Apply requested transformation. This function calculates the distribution with two sets of parameters, and uses these to scale the input table's columns. It takes 0.03 sec for 500k of individuals.

```
array_transform <- function(input_data = array1_dt_reshape, 
                           max_yr = 7, S_M_mean = 4, I_M_mean = 2) {
  tictoc::tic()
  # First calculate the distribution function values to apply to all individuals, 
  #   depending on year.
  p_S_M_vals <- sapply(0:max_yr, function(x){pnorm(x, S_M_mean, 1)})
  p_I_M_vals <- sapply(0:max_yr, function(x){pnorm(x, I_M_mean, 1)})

  # For each year, scale S_M + I_M by the respective distribution functions.
  #   This solution relies on the fact that each ID has 8 rows every time,
  #   so we can recycle the 8 values in the distribution functions.
  output <- input_data %>% 
    # group_by(ID) %>%  <-- Not needed
    mutate(S_M = S_F * p_S_M_vals,
           I_M = I_F * p_I_M_vals,
           R_M = S_M + I_M)  # %>% ungroup  <-- Not needed
  tictoc::toc()
  return(output)
}


array1_output <- array_transform(array1_dt_reshape)
```

**Results**

```
head(array1_output)
   ID year I_F R_F S_F          S_M        I_M         R_M
1   1    0  16  76  23 7.284386e-04  0.3640021   0.3647305
2   1    1  46  96  80 1.079918e-01  7.2981417   7.4061335
3   1    2  27  57  76 1.729010e+00 13.5000000  15.2290100
4   1    3  42  64  96 1.523090e+01 35.3364793  50.5673837
5   1    4  74  44  57 2.850000e+01 72.3164902 100.8164902
6   1    5  89  90  64 5.384606e+01 88.8798591 142.7259228
7   1    6  23  16  44 4.299899e+01 22.9992716  65.9982658
8   1    7  80  46  90 8.987851e+01 79.9999771 169.8784862
9   2    0  16  76  23 7.284386e-04  0.3640021   0.3647305
10  2    1  46  96  80 1.079918e-01  7.2981417   7.406133
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jon Spring for your answer. In my example, the output is an array. Is it possible to have an array ? or maybe is it a bad idea to have an array as output ?

Comment: How can I obtain an 3D array as output ?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, but beyond my current knowledge. Here's some code that I think gets close but hangs for me:  `output <- array_transform(array1_dt_reshape) %>%
  select(-I_F, -R_F, -S_F) %>% gather(Var1, Freq, S_M:R_M) %>%
  mutate(year = if_else(year > 1,
                        paste0(year, "_years"),
                        paste0(year, "_year"))) %>%
  unite(Var1, c("year", "Var1"))

new_col_array <- output %>% filter(ID == "1") %>% pull(Var1)
output_as_array <- array(output, dim=c(1, length(new_col_array), ind), dimnames = list(NULL, new_col_array, individuals))`

Comment: Thank you very much Jon Spring ! I am testing each code line because I am not familiar with the dplyr package. It seems that the variable "ID" is not in ascending order using `arrange(ID)` !?

Comment: Yes, I think at present it's as character. Could replace end of Step 2 above with `mutate(ID = as.integer(ID);  arrange(ID)` and then it'll sort as expected.